# Chrome extension - permanent alarm

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set a periodical alarm to load data on background from time to time. When the extension is installed, the alarm is triggered after the delay correctly, no problem here. But then it goes away and no other repetition is done. I also tried to set `persistent=true` which prevents it from going to the inactive mode but still no difference in behavior.

manifest.json

```
{ 
...
"background": {
  "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "common.js", "background.js"]
  "persistent": false/true // tried both
},
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "alarms",
  "storage"
]
```

}

bgscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.alarms.create({delayInMinutes: 1});
});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function () {
    doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the description of [chrome.alarms.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms#method-create), you should also set `periodInMinutes` for repeating.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.alarms.create({delayInMinutes: 1, periodInMinutes: 1});
});
```